# Fedora 20 crashes momentarily on every boot, but system still running

Tags: fedora, crash

I am trying to figure out what is causing the momentary crash on every boot up, as observed in the output from `last` command:

```
user    pts/0        :0               Wed Jul 15 21:07   still logged in
user    :0           :0               Wed Jul 15 20:29   still logged in
reboot   system boot  3.15.3-200.fc20. Wed Jul 15 20:29   still running
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Jul 15 20:29 - crash  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.15.3-200.fc20. Wed Jul 15 20:29   still running
user    pts/2        :0               Wed Jul 15 17:51 - 19:17  (01:26)
...
user    :0           :0               Wed Jul 15 14:15 - 19:27  (05:11)
reboot   system boot  3.15.3-200.fc20. Wed Jul 15 14:12 - 19:27  (05:14)
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Jul 16 14:12 - crash  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.15.3-200.fc20. Wed Jul 16 14:12 - 19:27  (05:14)
user    pts/0        :0               Wed Jul 16 09:13 - 10:29  (01:15)
```

I tried to figure out what's wrong by querying the journald log, but I didn't find anything amiss except some private bus connection error and that sendmail got restarted again.

```
Jul 15 20:29:44 systemd[1]: Started Sendmail Mail Transport Agent.
Jul 15 20:29:44 systemd[1]: Starting Sendmail Mail Transport Client...
...
Jul 15 20:29:46 systemd[875]: Failed to open private bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/42/dbus/user_bus_socket: No such file or directory
...
Jul 15 20:29:51 systemd[1]: Stopping Sendmail Mail Transport Client...
Jul 15 20:29:51 systemd[1]: Stopping Sendmail Mail Transport Agent...
Jul 15 20:29:51 systemd[1]: Starting Sendmail Mail Transport Agent...
...
Jul 15 20:29:57 systemd[1862]: Failed to open private bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/dbus/user_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me how to figure out what is causing the crash?

Comment: It looks like a systemd user instance is trying to connect to the dbus session bus and fails. I do not know why that would be the case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1010572.